# axios promise returns correct value in "axios.all" function, but is undefined in the "then" function

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I'm following a tutorial in which data from the git API is requested and a scoring algorithm will order that data.

The battle function will take an array of two elements, i.e two github users. We retrieve the profile and score for eah user from the getUserData method

```
module.exports = {
  battle: function(players) {
      return axios.all(players.map(getUserData))
        .then(response => {
           response.forEach( each=>console.log(each));
           return response;
       })
  }
}
```

The getProfile and getRepos functions ork correctly in retrieving objects which have data on the users profile(username, followers, etc) and their repos(repo names, etc.). So I've omitted the code for both these functions as I already know they work for certain. Additionally, the calculateScore method also works and returns output as expected.

The console.log statement shows that the object with keys "profile" and "score" is correctly made, and prints out both the profile object data and the score as expected. So far so good.

```
function getUserData(player) {
  axios.all([
    getProfile(player),
    getRepos(player)
  ])
    .then(function(data) {
        var profile = data[0];
        var repos = data[1];

        console.log({
            profile: profile,
            score: calculateScore(profile, repos)
        })

        return {
            profile: profile,
            score: calculateScore(profile, repos)
        }
    })
}
```

**The Problem:**

The callback function in "battle" should receive an array of size 2, with each element containing the profile and score for that particular player. e.g:

```
[
 {
   profile: {profile data for player1...}
   score: 10 //or whatever the score is
 },
 {
   profile: {profile data for player2...}
   score: 2 //or whatever the score is
 }
]
```

but instead the callback function is receiving [undefined, undefined] as its input from the axios.all function

Correct me if I'm wrong, but in promises, isn't the output from the "axios.all" method supposed to be the input for the "then" method. So why am I getting undefined if the console.log statement shows that axios.all is outputting the correct data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getUserData` function does not return anything. Change it as below:

```
function getUserData(player) {
  return axios.all([
  // ...
  ]);
}
```

---

That behaviour is because you return an array of `undefined` values when you do `response.map` where you replace all the items with `undefined` (`console.log` returns `undefined`).

Instead, return the actual result from the asynchronous call:

```
module.exports = {
  battle: function(players) {
      return axios.all(players.map(getUserData))
        .then(response => {
            response.forEach(each => console.log(each));
            return response;
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping out. I tried your solution but it still gives an array of two undefined elements

Comment: @AndrewBrick Please update your question with the exact code that you are using now.

Comment: The problem definitely lies in the map function, I know for certain that getUserData returns actual data, but before it's passed into the "then" method, it needs to go through map, but map somehow makes it undefined